# Possibility with should/could/must/might

Tags: modal-verbs

Please share your thoughts about the following.

I am having trouble understanding why almost everyone here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245059/correct-modal-verb chooses "could". One guy has suggested to ask here also.

> It is possible for John to shift to architecture. John (should/could/must/might) shift to architecture.

So there are four options to choose from, please share your thoughts about why the 3 of them are not suitable and why 1 of them is the best answer.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
What confuses me is the preference of "could" over "might". A guy from the other forum mentioned that if it still confuses me, I should ask here.

Comment: I think you should edit your existing question on ELU and ask for clarification. Starting over on ELL seems counterproductive and precludes possible continued conversation where you started it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP asked the question on ELU and has a conversation over there that he or she is apparently abandoning.

Comment: Edit your question over there at ELU and ask for clarification.

Comment: To be fair, [this user was directed to ELL by an ELU veteran](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245059/correct-modal-verb#comment530996_245084), who wrote: "If you're still having trouble understanding how *possible* is used in the two different senses of *probability/likelihood* and *ability/capacity*, I think you should ask again on English Language Learners. It's not really what ELU is all about."

Comment: What's more, the ELU question has been closed as off-topic, with all 5 close voters suggesting it be asked over here.  I think it's fine leaving this question open, but perhaps the question could be elaborated a little to make it clearer what's confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible for John to shift to architecture.

Let's take them one by one:

> 1. John **should** shift to architecture. *This assumes that shifting to architecture is possible, but what it actually says is that shifting is recommended or desirable.*
> 2. John **could** shift to architecture. *This means that shifting to architecture is an option open to John which he is able to take if he wants to. That's essentially what your ‘base’ sentence means, too.*
> 3. John **must** shift to architecture.  *This means that John has no choice: he is required to shift to architecture. Again, it assumes that shifting is possible.*
> 4. John **might** shift to architecture. *Like #2, this addresses possibility; but it is about the possibility that John will in fact shift to architecture. Neither #2 nor the base sentence says anything about John's intention, as this one does.*

Comment: Adding on to this just to make sure it's clear: *could* means that something is possible but doesn't say anything about how likely it is. *might* means that it is somewhat likely and assumes that it is possible.